# I get errors when trying to perform a second query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is all of my PHP code.

```
define('DB_SERVER', "mysql.com");
define('DB_USER', "");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "!");
define('DB_DATABASE', "");
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `accountsToDo` ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $percentageOfMessages =($row["percentageOfMessages"]);  
    $RemoveDeletedAccounts =($row["RemoveDeletedAccounts"]);    
    $blacklistUsernames =($row["blacklistUsernames"]);  
    $userEmail =($row["userEmail"]);  
    $CUse =($row["CUse"]);  
    $CPa =($row["CPa"]);  
}
$conn->close();
?>
<ul> 
    <li id="percentageOfMessages"><?php echo $percentageOfMessages; ?></li>
    <li id="RemoveDeletedAccounts"><?php echo $RemoveDeletedAccounts; ?></li>
    <li id="blacklistUsernames"><?php echo $blacklistUsernames; ?></li>
    <li id="userEmail"><?php echo $userEmail; ?></li>
    <li id="CUse"><?php echo $CUse; ?></li>
    <li id="CPa"><?php echo $CPa; ?></li>
</ul>
```

My question is, after I get the values of that row. I want to go ahead and delete that row.

```
    $CUse =($row["CUse"]);  
    $CPa =($row["CPa"]);  
}

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$query = "DELETE FROM `accountsToDo` WHERE 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
$conn->query($query);

$conn->close();
?>
```

But when I put this right there, I get an error saying....

> Call to a member function close() on null

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Dont connect more than once in a script. One connection is good for the whole script

Comment: @RiggsFolly I removed the second $conn and I get this error `Call to a member function query()`

Comment: Its also better to write a DELETE in a more specific way i.e. `DELETE from table WHERE id=` and then you are sure you will only delete the correct row

Comment: Oh right you will have to remove the `$conn->close();` also. PHP does that automatically at end of execution

Comment: @RiggsFolly Okay, so get this error "Call to a member function query() on null in"  on this line `$conn->query($query);`

Comment: This code is all in the same script file? Right!

Comment: This is all one PHP file @RiggsFolly

Comment: In answer to _How would it possible for it delete something different than the original query_ If another script deletes the row you think you are deleting, then your code will delete the next oldest row, and not the same one you found using the select query above

Comment: @RiggsFolly Good point, I'll make the delete more specific once I get this fixed. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what it should be:

Also when you delete something. Make sure to define what to delete, or it will delete nothing/all!! See my adjustment below.

```
define('DB_SERVER', "mysql.com");
define('DB_USER', "");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "!");
define('DB_DATABASE', "");
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `accountsToDo` ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>
<ul> 
    <li id="percentageOfMessages"><?php echo $row["percentageOfMessages"]; ?></li>
    <li id="RemoveDeletedAccounts"><?php echo $row["RemoveDeletedAccounts"]; ?></li>
    <li id="blacklistUsernames"><?php echo $row["blacklistUsernames"]; ?></li>
    <li id="userEmail"><?php echo $row["userEmail"]; ?></li>
    <li id="CUse"><?php echo $row["CUse"]; ?></li>
    <li id="CPa"><?php echo $row["CPa"]; ?></li>
</ul>

$query = "DELETE FROM `accountsToDo` WHERE `id` = {$row['id']}";
$conn->query($query);

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: if output is more than one than which one is deleted so this query is wrong

Comment: Also if you are SELECTing with a LIMIT 1 There is no reason or need to retrieve the SINGLE result row in a while loop. Its just confusing when you read the code again in a week to make an amendment

Comment: Just checking, I was told that PHP does the `$conn->close();` by itself right? So should I put that or not?

Comment: When I ran this query in phpMyAdmin, it was working without having to specify the Where

Comment: There is also no earthly need to unload a perfectly good array i.e. `$row` into scalar variables in order to just output them in an HTML tag

Comment: @PhpisHardForMe Like I said earlier. **Your query will run** it is just not **bullet proof** i.e. there is no guarantee it will delete the **correct row**

Comment: @RiggsFolly, so would it make sense to do `$id =($row["id"]);` under the row and then for the query do `$query = "DELETE FROM `accountsToDo` WHERE `id` = '$id' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";` ?

Comment: **Absolutely perfect sense** But you can loose the `order by and limit` Of course I am assuming thats `id` is a unique, auto increment column

Comment: Thank you guys so much! Also, what symbol should i wrap the variable in? quotes? or the ` ?

Comment: You should learn to use parameterised queries. To protect your code from SQL Injection

Comment: @PhpisHardForMe for table names and column names use ` (backtick) and for values use quotes.

Comment: Alright, I did all of your guys suggestion but I'm still getting an error, "Call to a member function query()" on this line `$conn->query($query);`

Comment: @PhpisHardForMe **Parameterized queries** Every time you are using anything that comes in from an untrusted source

Comment: It's not an untrusted source. I'm 100% sure I don't have to worry about Parameterized queries in this specific case. I've used them before so I kinda know how they work

Comment: @RiggsFolly, you don't have to explain to me... I know how to use this shit, only here to help..... not gonna make his code. He has to figure that out himself... Just gonna help him so his code works

Comment: @Refilon Totally agree, that comment was aimed more at the OP than you. Apologise for ruffling your feathers

Comment: So issue is somewhere in the second query, because I took out those 3 lines and there's no errors anymore.